# TypeGraphql - @inputtype on typeorm

Tags: graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

Hello I need to check if there is an email in the database already:

with this:

```
return User.findOne({ where: { email } }).then((user) => {
  if (user) return false;
  return true;
});
```

I have the following inputtypes:

```
@InputType()
export class RegisterInput {
  @Field()
  @IsEmail({}, { message: 'Invalid email' })
  email: string;

  @Field()
  @Length(1, 255)
  name: string;

  @Field()
  password: string;
}
```

I would like to know if there is any way for me to validate the email in the inputtype? or just in my resolve:

```
@Mutation(() => User)
  async register(
    @Arg('data')
    { email, name, password }: RegisterInput,
  ): Promise<User> {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

    const user = await User.create({
      email,
      name,
      password: hashedPassword,
    }).save();

    return user;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can register your own decorator for `class-validator`

For example it can look something like this:

isEmailAlreadyExists.ts

```
import {
  registerDecorator,
  ValidationOptions,
  ValidatorConstraint,
  ValidatorConstraintInterface,
} from 'class-validator';
import { UserRepo } from '../../repositories/UserRepo';
import { InjectRepository } from 'typeorm-typedi-extensions';

@ValidatorConstraint({ async: true })
export class isEmailAlreadyExist
  implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  @InjectRepository()
  private readonly userRepo: UserRepo;

  async validate(email: string) {
    const user = await this.userRepo.findOne({ where: { email } });

    if (user) return false;
    return true;
  }
}

export function IsEmailAlreadyExist(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      options: validationOptions,
      constraints: [],
      validator: isEmailAlreadyExist,
    });
  };
}
```

If you're injecting dependencies than you should in inject it in `class-validator` too. Simply add to your main file this:

```
import { Container } from 'typedi';
import * as classValidator from 'class-validator';

classValidator.useContainer(Container);

...
const schema = await buildSchema({
    resolvers: [...],
    container: Container,
  });
```

Then you can use decorator in your InputType

```
import { InputType, Field } from 'type-graphql';
import { IsEmailAlreadyExist } from '../../../utils/validators/isEmailAlreadyExist';

@InputType()
export class YourInput {
  @Field()
  @IsEmailAlreadyExist()
  email: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually just figured this out myself for my own project.

You can simply add a validation on the email from `RegisterInput` argument and throw an error if the email already exists.

```
import { Repository } from 'typeorm'
import { InjectRepository } from 'typeorm-typedi-extensions'

...

// Use dependency injection in the resolver's constructor
constructor(
  @InjectRepository(User) private readonly userRepository: Repository<User>
) {}

...

// Your mutation
@Mutation(() => User)
async register(
  @Arg('data')
  { email, name, password }: RegisterInput,
): Promise<User> {
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

  const userWithEmail = this.userRepository.find({ email: email })

  // If a user with the email was found
  if (userWithEmail) {
    throw new Error('A user with that email already exists!')
  }

  const user = await User.create({
    email,
    name,
    password: hashedPassword,
  }).save();

  return user;
}
```

To use the `InjectRepository` make sure you add a "container" to your `buildSchema` function:

```
import { Container } from 'typedi'
...
const schema = await buildSchema({
  resolvers: [...],
  container: Container
})
```

Let me know if this works out for you? Thanks!